# Why is there issues/confusion with variable datatypes between android functions?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, type-conversion

As a new Android programmer, one of the frustrating things it seems is the necessity to convert datatypes between various built-in functions/commands including using SQLITE... unless I am really missing something here.  I have spent quite a bit of time on the internet and more specifically here trying to determine the best way to handle some of this.

Here are a couple key ones that I am dealing with right now...

In my activity, I have a SWITCH.   The switch uses apparently Boolean for Off/On (no problem) with the setChecked()/isChecked() methods that require or return a Boolean variable (no problem either).    I am storing this selection in an SQLITE database which I believe is rather common, but SQLITE doesn't have a Boolean datatype, just INTEGER. So, for both these functions, to go back and forth, we have to convert the integer to boolean and vice versa... and that seems to require several lines of code to do so... each time.  Is that correct?

Also in my activity I have a Spinner with an array setup in values/array.xml with the string values.    I can use getSelectedItem().toString() to get the string chosen and I can store that in SQLITE text field.   But to set that Spinner with the data from the SQLITE, you have to have several lines of code, for each Spinner, to scan the array to find the right value and set the "position".   Shouldn't there be a function or method to set the Spinner by value?

Another, as is recommended by almost everyone using SQLITE (and databases in general), an AutoIncrement field is ideal and that is an INTEGER.    Functions like SQLiteDatabase.insert returns the inserted record # as a long.  So to store that variable and use it for updating purposes, the LONG has to be converted to an INTEGER (which "could" be problematic) and vice versa.   Again, is that correct?

I do realize the SQLITE wasn't originally written for Android/Java... but if it is a relative mainstay in that programming, shouldn't there be built-in considerations for these issues... again, unless I am missing something?

So, after spending the better part of night working on some code that was erroring out, basically because of these issues (and a few more), and rewritting a bunch of it hopefully correct, I have made a pretty jumbled mess and am losing track of what variable needs to be what to work.

I probably made this whole posting more confusing because as of right now, I am really getting confused...  So, the question is... am I missing something here or is all this normal?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a chat forum, but a Q&A site. Please ask a question and get straight to the point.

Comment: @juergen     I believe I asked a question, with each case to see if I am doing this correctly or am I missing a Java/Android command that would make it easier.   Sorry you don't feel that way, but these were legit questions.

Comment: @Peter No, you asked **a bunch** of questions. And showed **no effort** (in code). And didn't go **directly** to the point. How are we supposed to give you a resolutive answer?

Comment: Your right, I did ask a bunch of related questions as opposed to posting 4 different identical postings.... because all were based on the same premis of the title.   As for no code, didn't realize every posting required code with every question when the actual code is not wrong, but asking if there was an unknown easier way of doing things.

Comment: As a 35yr programmer in a variety of languages, I have helped newbies to a language on other sites/forums... with QUESTIONS just like this.   That is the benefit of sites like this. As a newbie to Android/Java I guess I expected the same courtesy from fellow programmers instead of critiquing how postings are made.   Guess I was wrong.  Sorry if I offended anyone on here... I was just looking for some friendly and constructive help (similar to how InvertedNetwork did below).   I'll be careful on what I ask and how I ask it in the future.  Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Switch: yes you need to store boolean as Integer (0 o 1)
2. Spinner: you should create a HashMap and put the values there, description and position at startup. Then you would get the position with it description. Something like:

   Map mSpinnerPositionsMap = new HashMap();

   mSpinnerPositionsMap.put("Choice1", 1);

Then you can retrieve the position with the Choice1 desc, that would stored in the db.

```
   int position = mSpinnerPositionsMap.get("Choice1");
```

3. That conversion won't be problematic the SQLite Integer is not the same that Java integer, so you will be good using Java long for ids. Also by default, all SQLite tables have an autoincremental ROWID field, so you don't need to add the AUTOINCREMENTAL in most cases, read the [SQLite doc on it](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

4. That is normal, but you can use an ORM if you don't want to handle the manual convertions and the code to interact with the DB. Take a look at [this list](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-best-android-orms/)

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for you reply.   For #1, then because of that, you have to convert to use SetChecked or IsChecked for the control... correct?   For #3, so if I understand this correct, you DON'T need an   _id    field that is autoincrement then?   Thats interesting, all Android SQLite tutorials have them.    I will try that.

Comment: The _id field is only useful when you are using an adapter for the data that uses a cursor, then it's easier to hook it up. But otherwise the _id field is not needed.